# What kind of app I can develop for Android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

Recently I went through http://developer.android.com/wear/index.html
and play with sample apps like
AndroidWearChat, AndroidWearNotificationTest,AndroidWearRecipeHelp

so know to get going

I am curious that what kind of apps I can develop for Android wear with current SDK support?
Also I want to know that is it compulsory that it can be only used by paring with Android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [Android Wear Design documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/wear/index.html) and the [Android Wear Creative Vision](http://developer.android.com/design/wear/creative-vision.html) to understand in detail what types of applications you can build with Android Wear. In general, Android Wear is intended to not get in the user's way, so the main goal is to provide contextual information (via bridged notifications and contextual notifications). You can implement wearable apps that run directly on the wearable device and these can make use of the sensors that the device has (such as accelerometer, heart-rate sensor, pedometer, etc.). The documentation has a chapter that describes [the structure of wearable apps](http://developer.android.com/design/wear/structure.html) in detail. Also, have a look at the code samples (that you can download using the SDK manager). To give you an idea, here is a short selection of the samples included:

- AgendaData: transfers calendar entries from a phone to a connected wearable, which then shows notifications for current events
- ElizaChat: uses Remote Input to implement the infamous Eliza chatbot on your wearable
- FindMyPhone: can be started on the wearable by saying "OK, Google. Start Find my Phone". It will then play a sound on your connected phone (which has to be in reach, though).
- GridViewPager: example for using one of the UI patterns of Android Wear, the GridViewPager
- JumpingJack: uses the accelerometer to count how many jumping jacks you performed
- Notifications: plenty of examples for how to create notifications
- and more...